# Construction of purely radial harmonic function

Tags: harmonic-functions, spherical-coordinates, laplacian, partial-differential-equations

So my question is

In a spherical shell with $1<r<2$ construct a purely radial harmonic function v such that it takes the values $5$ and $4$ at $r=1$ and $r=2$ , respectively

I know that I should use the Laplacian spherical coordinates

and take  $Δv=0$

The spherical coordinates

$$\Delta v = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2 \psi}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\psi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}\left(\sin\psi \frac{\partial v}{\partial \psi}\right).$$

when I set derivatives in angular directions equal to zero I get

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \right). $$

I took the integral and got the solution of $v(r)=$$c_2$- 
$\frac{c_1}{r}\$            $

But not sure how to proceed from here and Am I solving it the correct way?

Can someone help me with this